# Silverlight for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0

I have looked around but could not find any answer to my question. 
Is there a Silverlight toolkit for Visual Studio 2012? I tried to install Silverlight 5 but did not work, Visual Studio was still asking for a Silverlight installation and did not allow Silverlight project creation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this answer](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/256526.aspx/1) the Silverlight toolkit is already installed as Part of VS2012 RC